# Writing different rows of csv into columns keeping the same header? - Python

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, dynamic, zip

With a CSV file of format

```
   Name  X    Y    L   W 
   alpha 100  200  50  20
   beta  200  250  30  40
   ...
```

How can we convert the CSV into format

```
  Name  X     Y   L   W   Name  X    Y    L   W  
  alpha 100  200  50  20  beta  200  250  30  40
```

The maximum number of rows(excluding header) are 4. Could anybody guide how to build the dynamic dictionary for such scenario and zip to obtain the result in the format described above using python?

Comment: And where do you want the third data row to go to?

Comment: and what you try?

Comment: @blhsing also in the same row as first two rows. (2nd row would look like - 1strowdata, 2ndrowdata, 3rd rowdata, 4th rowdata), as mentioned in question, csv has data that varies between 1 and 4 rows(excluding header).

Answer (score 1):

simple straightforward script if data is not huge.

```
import csv
rd = csv.reader(open("input.csv"), delimiter=' ', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL, skipinitialspace=True)
header = rd.next()
wr = csv.writer(open("output.csv", "w"), delimiter=' ')
data_lines = 0 
data = []
for line in rd:
    data += line
    data_lines += 1
wr.writerow(header*data_lines)
wr.writerow(data)
```

`skipinitialspace=True` is to remove extra space in delimiter (considering input csv is `' '` separated).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

# read file
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')

# split by row and concatenate along columns
res = pd.concat([df.iloc[[i]].reset_index(drop=True) \
                 for i in range(len(df.index))], axis=1)

# export to csv
res.to_csv('out.csv', index=False)
```

Result for 2 rows:

```
    Name    X    Y   L   W  Name    X    Y   L   W
0  alpha  100  200  50  20  beta  200  250  30  40
```

Comment: i get current result is
`,   Name  X    Y    L   W ,   Name  X    Y    L   W 
0,   alpha 100  200  50  20,   beta  200  250  30  40` has comma.

Comment: @BearBrown, Exactly, this is the same as the desired output in your question. CSV files generally have commas [hence Comma-Separated values], use the `sep` parameter for [`pd.DataFrame.to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) for other options.

Comment: i just try it for my self, i am not OP

Comment: @BearBrown, Ah, I see, the above comment should still apply :).